# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting custom formula not working

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I am trying to shade all rows that are associated with a specific value of column B as `=$B2="BAMS"`, yet custom formula keeps saying the wrong formula.

Any idea?

[image: custom formula box show error]

Comment: on the image the first parenthesis are wrong. and also it should be B1 coz you start at A1 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJIWN.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this: 

```
=$B1="BAMS"
```

[image: 0]

.

Comment: thanks it worked, but why I need to start from B1, I tried B2 and it give me all row that has no BAMS

Comment: @kernel now I am not sure what are you after... I got the impression that you want to color the rows that do contain BAMS. if you want opposite then the formula should be `=$B1<>"BAMS"` or `=AND($B1<>"BAMS", B1<>"")` if you want to offset it by one row then B2 is ok

Comment: Ok. I found that if I want to color all rows with BAMS, then all B with odd number do work (B1 or B3 or B5 etc ..), but if I want to color all rows offset by one then all even number of B works (B2, or B4, ...).

Comment: that is not entirely true - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oag4o.png